# Sending signals to running Upstart job

Tags: process, node.js, upstart, background-process

How can I send signals or events to a running Upstart job?
I run a Node.js HTTP server with Upstart as a daemon and sometimes need to put it into maintenance mode for backups and stuff.

I'd like to send a signal to the node process, which then will response with the maintenance mode.

Can I do something like this? `initctl sendsignal MyNodeDaemon maintenance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note currently, although we do plan to add such a feature. However, you can still do what you want using the status command. Something like:

```
pid=$(initctl status MyNodeDaemon | grep /running | awk '{print $NF}')
[ ! -z "$pid" ] && kill -SIGFOO $pid
```

Comment: usually awk does not require a grep to filter the input since there is a built in functionality for this in awk

Comment: If the daemon provides a CLI, would it be possible to send some CLI input to the daemon?

Comment: @jamesodhunt I see that it has been a year and a half since you wrote this. Is it still the case? I'd sure like to send SIGUSR1/2...